# install natgrid in matplotlib in the environment of python 2.7

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm quit new in using python. The current version I'm using is 2.7. I need to employ function mncontour in minuit which requires the installation of natgrid as additional toolkit for matplotlib. I downloaded natgrid 0.2.1 with a file named setup.py in it. I ran this setup.py through python shell without reaching any error. But it seems that the installation was not succeed. Anyone has any idea how the installation can be done? Many thanks.

Liang

Answer (score 2):

Could you please provide some more information on this topic.

1. what operating system you are working with ( some offer more support than others for python)
2. have you installed python headers, and a C/C++ compiler in your environment? ( numerical libraries might require native code to speed up the computation)
3. Have you tried a package manager for python ( such as easy or pip)? Both work on both windows and unixes, and usually download and install all the needed packages to make your module working.
4. A piece of the setup's output before setup.py finished would help us help you greatly.

---

Python for Windows [Nt - 7] is compiled with either cygwin or mingw, thus you not only need the python environment, but also said compiler, and python headers. If you want a more point and click install, then there's this professor at this university who maintains a good and up to date repository of scientific python modules, that depend on native extensions ( among which numpy, scipy, matplotlib).
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Manuals to setup mingw and python :

https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html

MingW can be downloaded from here:

http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: 1. The operating system is windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Best option for installing natgrid is from conda

```
conda install -c jochym natgrid=0.2
```