# conda install matplotlib's natgrid python toolkit on windows 64

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

Trying to install the `natgrid` matplotlib toolkit (https://github.com/matplotlib/natgrid) on Windows 64 through Anaconda.

I can only find one package which is supported on Windows and that's here https://anaconda.org/rios/natgrid

When I run `conda install -c rios natgrid=0.2` 
it returns `PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '`

Does anybody know what causes the error, is there another package or a workaround I can use to be able to use the `natgrid` toolkit within the Anaconda python distribution on Windows?

Comment: have you try conda update ? in terminal `conda update conda`

Comment: thanks @Dadep - I've done this and now getting an `UnsatisfiableError:` instead of the `PackageNotFoundError:`, which is revealing a python versioning issue with the `natgrid` package. At least this error gives me something to work with though.

Comment: are you sure anaconda is correctly install ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to update conda : `conda update conda`

also you can directly download file from  :

https://anaconda.org/rios/natgrid/files

you can use as alternative pip install :

`python -m pip install .\natgrid-0.2.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`

or this alternative from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902724/install-natgrid-in-matplotlib-in-the-environment-of-python-2-7) :

`conda install -c jochym natgrid=0.2`

Comment: Thanks, but I think jochym package is for Linux only. I had tried the pip install method before posting, but it said it 'wasn't a supported wheel on this platform'. However, since upgrading to python 3.6 pip install appears to have been successful.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (win64 with conda):

```
conda install -c rios natgrid
```

From [here](https://anaconda.org/rios/natgrid)